# Android phonegap , www folder issue

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

When ever i try to replace my www folder in phonegap + android app's, project structure,It allways shows a error; index.html not found, what should be done to overcome this problem ?
working on : eclipse ide

Comment: Is there any reason to replace the www folder instead of running cordova build or prepare? Just in case, remember that you can work in the project root www, and then run cordova build that will update the www folder files in the corresponding platform. Omit my comment in case you already are aware of this

Comment: My problem is, 
Step 1 : Add platform android
         Cordova platform add android
Step 2 : I made some changes and then run the application, it     starts without any issue.
Step 3 : Now i copy paste a directory in Css or any file anywhere inside the WWW directory, App stops working & only a dailog appears mentioning index.html not found.

I'm unable to detect the wrong in this.